# How to cache messages in Python's log module?

Tags: python, logging

Our Python application needs to run on a new HW with write limitation.
I was asked to reduce writing as much as possible.
After changing verbosity, and reduce log messages, I was thinking of creating a cache mechanism that will log messages and write them once a day in one transaction.
How would I do that?
I was thinking if inherit and override the  _log() method, but not sure how to write  "one" message out of all the old messages, while making the log file still appears as with many messages.

Comment: Once a day? Is your system very stable?

Comment: See [**`MemoryHandler`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#memoryhandler): *Flushing occurs whenever the buffer is full, or when an event of a certain severity or greater is seen.*

Comment: @PeterSmith.                                                                                                 1. i have no choice. new HW is based on a flash with max writing. we must prefer less log than HW malfunction.                                                             2. wil look at the MemoryHandler. At first glance it looks exactly what i need! thanks.